# How do I find all command blocks on my server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I opened my server and I saw that my admins created a policy and since I'm an owner I can delete it.

The policy is:

- 3 warns = kick
- 3 kicks = ban

This shows up in the chat, and I want to delete it but I can't find the command block for it!

[image]

So the main question is: How do I locate all command blocks in my server?

Comment: What do these command blocks have to do with kicks and bans? Command blocks can't use those server commands.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer the question, but we may be able to find alternatives to removing the concerned command blocks in order to stop these "policies". Can you briefly explain how they are implemented?

Comment: I didn't specify in the edit comments, but the OP had the image URL in the post, but they didn't have it linked properly. I edited it back in, which should hopefully explain the link between the policy, and the use of the command blocks

Comment: Looks like a `tellraw`. If that's the case, the punishments will still need to be handed out manually. Then some alternatives include `enable-command-block=false` in `server.properties` / revoke admin permissions until they tell you where the command block is / make a new command block that prints enough blank lines to push the text off the chat history.

Comment: @54D you should post that as an answer, with the note that this command will disable *all* command blocks

Comment: I'm not sure. Asker requests a way to locate all command blocks, not resolve his particular issue.

Comment: @54D don't get caught in the x-y problem trap.  Solve his real problem (rogue admins adding command blocks they shouldn't), not just what the title says.

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot, the "policies" look like mere chat messages broadcasted to online players through `tellraw`.

If that is the case, the punishments will still need to be handed out manually by your admins. Then, instead of searching for the command block(s) causing this issue, some solutions to removing these messages include:

- changing the `enable-command-block` option to `false` in `server.properties`, but do note that this will disable *all command blocks* on the server;
- revoking admin permissions until they tell you where the command block(s) is(/are); or
- making a new command block that prints enough blank lines to push the text off the chat history